# Passing array as a parameter in kendo ui

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I am trying to pass an array as a parameter from kendo ui data source. I sue the traditional way but the list if always null. Any help will be appreciated.

### JS Code

```
read: {
      url: application.getWebRoot() + "api/reportbuilder",
      type: "GET",
      traditional: true,
      data: () => {
       return { dataTypes: [1, 2, 3] }
}
```

### MVC Controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route]
public IEnumerable<ReportRowDto> Get(int[] dataTypes)
{
        //dataTypes is null
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the [FromUri] attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route]
public IEnumerable<ReportRowDto> Get([FromUri]int[] dataTypes)
{
        return null;
}
```